# Проблема с иерархией классов

Tags: c#, ооп, классы, generics

Здравствуйте, уважаемые! У  меня возник следующий вопрос. Допустим я имею некий класс такого вида

```
public class Basis 
{
    public int Id {get; set; }

    public string Name {get; set; }
}
```

и несколько наследников от него, которые представляют собой записи из таблиц некой бд (доступ к бд через ORM):

```
public class First : Basis    
{
    public static IEnumerable<First> GetAll()
    {
        var data = new MyDataContext(); 
        return from item in data.FirstDataSet
               select new First { Id = item.Id, Name = item.Name;
    }
}

public class Second : Basis    
{
    public static IEnumerable<Second> GetAll()
    {
        var data = new MyDataContext(); 
        return from item in data.SecondDataSet
               select new Second { Id = item.Id, Name = item.Name;
    }
}
```

Как можно увидеть оба класса почти одинаковы. Каждый имеет статический метод для получения всех элементов данного типа из базы, и отличаются методы только типами возвращаемого значения и таблицами (**FirstDataSet** и **SecondDataSet**) к которым происходит обращение. Мне кажется что всю эту функциональность можно вынести в базовый класс и каким-то образом все это сделать короче, избавившись от дублирования кода, но не могу сообразить как. Может у кого-то есть какие нибудь идеи? Заранее спасибо

Comment: А кто будет знать в случае общей реализации объект какого класса-потомка создавать? Не лучше ли все таки оставить реализацию на плечах потомков?

Comment: Лучше разделить логику доступа к данным и сущности модели.

Лучше НЕ делать методы доступа к данным статическими.

Если ваш контекст поддержует типизированные коллекции, то можно легко провернуть вашу идею примерно таким методом в базовом классе:

IEnumerable<T> GetAll

Comment: >Лучше разделить логику доступа к данным и сущности модели

зачем?

>Лучше НЕ делать методы доступа к данным статическими

почему?

Comment: @JuniorTwo: По той же причине, по которой не стоит всю логику приложения делать в OnClick: чем меньше ответственностей у класса, тем лучше. Сущности модели должны быть простыми, не содержать приватных данных, быть по существу не более чем состоянием. (Иначе вы не сможете отобразить их на таблицу.) А логика доступа к данным — штука более умная, и должна уметь изменяться не затрагивая базу данных.

Comment: @JuniorTwo: Не используйте наследование для того, чтобы уменьшить повторное использование кода, оно для этого не предназначено.

Просто воспользуйтесь сторонним хелпером: http://pastebin.com/8eWP1ma3

Answer (score 1):

Можно. Делаешь базовый класс абстрактым с generic-параметром, ограниченным интерфейсом. Делаешь метод GetAll, тороый в select передаёт абстрактный метод GetItem. Наследники реализуют GetItem. FirstDataSet и SecondDataSet реализуют нужный интерфейс. Вероятно, интерфейс тоже generic.